# Wordpress: Clean up of HTML in old posts

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm building a new theme for a client. Part of the job will be to migrate old content.

Looking in detail at the old posts, they are very 'dirty', copied without care from various word processors and littered with HTML

There's 118 blog posts (ie not huge). But I can see, looking at the wider picture, that the problem I am describing could be huge in certain migration cases.

How can I clean these up?

As far as I can see, the main offenders are `style="*"`, `<span>`, `<div>`. Empty lines with `&nbsp;`

If I import these then presumably I can log the range. So I need to build (some) SQL queries.

Would it be more efficient to import into a clean WP install?

Comment: There's no simple solution to this. You'd need a plugin or write code to scrub the posts.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm seeking help with.

Comment: For instance, the regex `<span (.*)>` will find any opening span tag. Contributions of other 'dirty' code examples welcomed. Maybe this is a more general discussion as I am aware that only a certain amount of effort is worthwhile for 118 posts.